# Redhat | How to compile Python 2.6 for 64bit

Tags: python, redhat

I'm trying to compile Python 2.6 for 64bit, I tried various compile commands but not sure whether those are correct

```
./configure --with-universal-archs=32-bit --prefix="$HOME/python"
make
make install
```

What is the correct syntax ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly doesn't work? Do you get any error message?

Try simple compilation without installing first:

```
$ cd path/to/python/source
$ ./configure
$ make all
... wait for some time ...
$ make test  # this runs python's test suite, you can usually skip this
$ ./python   # note the ./ runs the just installed python instead of system's python
$ # note: do not run make install yet, or you will override system's python, see below
```

also, make sure you have make (GNU Make or otherwise) installed.

Where did you get the source? If you're getting it directly from the repository, there is a chance that the source is broken or you may need to re-run autotool.

After testing that the compilation actually works, then you can:

```
$ cd path/to/python/source/
$ ./configure --prefix=/where/you/want/to/install/it
$ make all
... wait for some time ...
$ make test  # this runs python's test suite, you can usually skip this
$ make install
```